How do I control the horizontal space between dt and dd in this grid-based description list?
I'm trying to create a concert set list that looks like this:
I:   Song 1, Song 2, Song 3, Song 4, Song 5,
     Song 6, Song 7

II:  Song 10, Song 11, Song 12, ...

E:   Song 20

Here is the code I've tried. It almost does what I want, except that I can't find how to control the width of the gutter between each dt and dd. I want to reduce the gap. I've noted in the CSS the various things I've tried.
I'm a beginner at HTML/CSS so I'd also welcome suggestions if there's a better approach to doing this. I want this to be responsive, and avoid older things (e.g. float) that I've read can be accomplished better using more modern features (e.g. grid and flex).


   * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
   }

   body {
      background-color: black;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      color: white;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 90%;
   }
   .headline-div {
     margin-top: 1em;
     margin-bottom: 1em;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 110%;
     color: red;
   }

   .setlist-dl {
     display: grid;
     column-gap: 0; /* Thought this would reduce the gap but no */
     grid-template-columns: max-content auto;
   }
   .setlist-dt {
     grid-column-start: 1;
     color: yellow;
     #margin-right: 0; /* Also tried this */
   }
   .setlist-dd {
     grid-column-start: 2;
     margin-bottom: 10px; /* put some vertical space between each set */
   }
   .setlist-songs-ul {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
   }
   .setlist-song-li {
     color: green;
     display: inline; /* makes it horizontal */
   }

   /* Show outlines of divs and dl components for troubleshooting */
   div, dt, dd, dl {
      outline-style: dotted;
      outline-color: green;
      outline-width: 1px;
   }
   */
<html>

<body>
<!-- SHOW -->
<div class="headline-div">
  <span id="1981">5/1/81 [Fri] Grateful Dead - Hampton Coliseum, Hampton, VA</span>
</div>
<div>
  <dl class="setlist-dl">
    <!-- SETLIST 1 -->
    <dt class="setlist-dt">
      I:
    </dt>
    <dd class="setlist-dd">
      <ul class="setlist-songs-ul">
        <li class="setlist-song-li">Alabama Getaway></li>
        <li class="setlist-song-li">Promised Land,</li>
        <li class="setlist-song-li">Friend Of The Devil></li>
        <li class="setlist-song-li">Me & My Uncle></li>
        <li class="setlist-song-li">Big River,</li>
        <li class="setlist-song-li">Althea></li>
        <li class="setlist-song-li">Little Red Rooster,</li>
        <li class="setlist-song-li">Tennessee Jed></li>
        <li class="setlist-song-li">Let It Grow></li>
        <li class="setlist-song-li">Deal</li>
      </ul>
    </dd>
    <!-- SETLIST 2 -->
    <dt class="setlist-dt">
      II:
    </dt>
    <dd class="setlist-dd">
      <ul class="setlist-songs-ul">
        <li class="setlist-song-li">Feel Like A Stranger></li>
        <li class="setlist-song-li">Franklin's Tower></li>
        <li class="setlist-song-li">Lost Sailor></li>
        <li class="setlist-song-li">Saint Of Circumstance></li>
        <li class="setlist-song-li">He's Gone></li>
        <li class="setlist-song-li">The Other One></li>
        <li class="setlist-song-li">Drums></li>
        <li class="setlist-song-li">Space></li>
        <li class="setlist-song-li">The Wheel></li>
        <li class="setlist-song-li">Wharf Rat></li>
        <li class="setlist-song-li">Sugar Magnolia</li>
      </ul>
    </dd>
    <!-- SETLIST 3 -->
    <dt class="setlist-dt">
      E:
    </dt>
    <dd class="setlist-dd">
      <ul class="setlist-songs-ul">
        <li class="setlist-song-li">U.S. Blues</li>
      </ul>
    </dd>
  </dl>
</div>
</body>
</html>




You tried setting margin-right on the <dt> elements, but that defaults to 0.
Set margin-left on the <dd> elements.
I found this by examining the <dd> and <dt> elements in Developer Tools. Looking at the layout tab for each showed where space was being added by the browser by default.

Screenshot from Firefox Developer Tools

That indeed is the answer. If possible, could you add to your answer a link to where this is documented, or something that would help me in the future to answer questions like this myself? I did quite a bit of searching before posting this question, to no avail.

Thanks for the technique for analyzing/understanding this sort of problem.
